# Arrange column data into rows in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a table which the below data:-

```
t,me,ma,mi,sd,data_id
'2010-04-14 00:00:00','12.6941','12.6941','12.6941','12.6941',1
'2010-04-14 00:00:00','12.3851','12.3851','12.3851','12.3851',2
'2010-04-14 00:00:00','11.6145','11.6145','11.6145','11.6145',3
'2010-04-14 00:10:00','12.3890','12.3890','12.3890','12.3890',1
'2010-04-14 00:10:00','12.1836','12.1836','12.1836','12.1836',2
'2010-04-14 00:10:00','11.3887','11.3887','11.3887','11.3887',3
```

i want the data to be arranged like this:-

```
t,1_me,1_ma,1_mi,1_sd,2_me,2_ma,2_mi,2_sd,3_me,3_ma,3_mi,3_sd
'2010-04-14 00:00:00','12.6941','12.6941','12.6941','12.6941','12.3851','12.3851','12.3851','12.3851','11.6145','11.6145','11.6145','11.6145'
'2010-04-14 00:10:00','12.3890','12.3890','12.3890','12.3890','12.1836','12.1836','12.1836','12.1836','11.3887','11.3887','11.3887','11.3887'
```

Can anyone please help me in ordering this data?

Comment: use unpivot method

Comment: Why did you tag Oracle?

Comment: @Uchiha_Itachi : Can you give me the query for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t,listagg(me||','||ma||','||mi||','||sd,',') within group(order by t)  
from table_name 
group by t  
order by t;
```

I have used this in Oracle,similarly you can use `string_agg()` function equivalent in Postgres.